# How to find out iOS version

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, version

Is it possible to read the iOS version (4.2.1, 4.3.3, etc.) running a MonoTouch app? If so, how?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion`.

Comment: How about major and minor numeric?

Comment: @Kenny see here: goo.gl/PzUEu

Comment: You can use   ´new Version(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion)´  to get an instance of System.Version

Comment: Or, easier, [call `CheckSystemVersion`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18568639/458193) if you need it for a boolean condition.

Answer (score 11):

If you only need it for a boolean condition, there is a convenience method:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (6, 0)) // at least 6.0
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, the above can check versions like 6.0, 6.1 but not "9.3.1" and "9.3.2".

Answer (score 6):

In MonoTouch:

To get the Major version use:

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion.Split('.')[0]
```

For minor version use:

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion.Split('.')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a .net System.Version class to convert from string.

```cs
var str = "3.5.3858.2";
Version version = Version.TryParse(str,out version) ? version : null;
if(version != null)
{
    // version.Major
    // version.Minor
    // version.Build
}
```